# Show notification before redirect in jQuery post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to show a notification of success before redirecting the user to another page. I'm using Apprise plugin with jQuery 1.7. The problem is that it redirects without showing the notification. If I take out the redirect, the notification works perfectly. Thanks for any help.

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"create/process_vote.php",
            data: { answerid: aid },
                success: function(){
                    $(".status").text('Thank you for voting!');
                    $(".status").fadeIn("slow");
                    $(".status").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
                    window.location.href = "results.php?id=" + aid;
                }
    });
```

Comment: You could try with a `setTimeout` call to redirect, the reason I think is that `$(".status").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000)` runs async, so the effect does not have time to execute and the redirect occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function(){
  $(".status").text('Thank you for voting!');
  $(".status").fadeIn("slow");
  $(".status").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);

  setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "results.php?id=" + aid; }, 2000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[window.confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm)**

```
success: function(){
                    $(".status").text('Thank you for voting!');
                    $(".status").fadeIn("slow");
                    $(".status").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                      // if user agreed
                      // window.confirm() in short just confirm()
                      if(window.confirm('Are you sure?')) { 
                          window.location.href = "results.php?id=" + aid;
                      }

                    });

                }
```

Comment: Can just be written as `if(confirm('Are you sure?'))` :)

Answer (score 0):

Apprise documentation shows it has a callback function. Put the redirect code within the callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    apprise('Redirect?', {'verify' : true}, function(r){
        if (r) {
            window.location = 'http://google.com'
        }
    })
});
```

[Apprise Docs](http://thrivingkings.com/apprise/)